# error type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, payable

I get the following error

> type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address
> payable on the withdraw function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract sendMoneyExamples{
    uint public getRecivedMoney;
    function reciveMoney()public payable{
        getRecivedMoney=getRecivedMoney+msg.value;
    }
    function getBalance()view public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function withdraw()public {
        address payable to = msg.sender;
        to.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }
    function withdrawato(address payable _to)public{
        _to.transfer(getBalance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the 'to' variable is address payable whereas the type of msg.sender is address. You can't implicitly convert an address to address payable as the error states. Remove the payable keyword from the to variable and it will be fine.